# legendre polynomial prove using recurrence relations

Tags: legendre-polynomials

Equation 1: 
$$P_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } n = 0; \\
              & \\
x, & \text{ if } n = 1; \\
              & \\
\dfrac{1}{n}[(2n-1)xP_{n-1}(x)+(n-1)P_{n-2}(x)], & \text{ if } n \geq 2.
\end{cases}$$

Equation 2: 
$$P'_{n+1} - 2xP'_n + P'_{n-1} = P_n$$

Using equation 1 and 2, show that for $n \geq1$, $$P'_{n+1}-P'_{n-1}=(2n+1)P_n$$

My attempt:

From equation 1: 
$$P_n(x) = 1 + x + \dfrac{1}{n} \left((2n-1)xP_{n-1}(x)+(n-1)P_{n-2}(x)\right)$$

Differentiate with respect to $x$: 
$$P'_n(x) = 1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\left((2n-1)xP'_{n-1}(x) + (2n-1)P_{n-1}(x) + (n-1)P'_{n-2}(x)\right) + P'_{n-1} \cdots (3)$$

Substitute (3) into equation 2:

$$P_n = P'_{n+1} - 2x\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\left((2n-1)xP'_{n-1}(x)+(2n-1)P_{n-1}(x) + (n-1)P'_{n-2}(x)\right)\right) + P'_{n-1}$$

$$P_n = P'_{n+1} - 2x \left(1 + \dfrac{2n-1}{n}xP'_{n-1} + \dfrac{2n-1}{n}P_{n-1} + \dfrac{n-1}{n}P'_{n-2}\right)+ P'_{n-1}$$

Need advise if I have done correct so far & how should I proceed? Kind of stuck. Thanks

From your advice:

$$P'_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n}\left[(2n+1)(P_{n} + xP'_n ) + nP'_{n-1}\right]$$

$$P'_{n+1} - P'_{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}(2n+1)(P_{n} + xP'_n )$$

Replace $P_n$ with equation (2),

$$P'_{n+1} -P'_{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}\left( (2n+1)(P'_{n+1}-2xP'_n+P'_{n-1}+xP'_n) + nP'_{n-1}\right)$$

$$n(P'_{n+1}-P'_{n-1}) = (2n+1)(P'_{n+1}-xP'n+P'_{n-1})+ nP'_{n-1}$$

When I expand the above, it will be complicated and can't get $P'_{n+1}-P'_{n-1}=(2n+1)P_n$ still.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you are doing it right, but expanding might not help. It'd be clearer to write as follows. Dropping the $(x)$ suffix and differentiating for Eq 1 in $(n+1)$

$$P'_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n}\left[(2n+1)(P_{n} + xP'_n ) + nP'_{n-1}\right]$$

$$P'_{n+1} - P'_{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}(2n+1)(P_{n} + xP'_n )$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi I have done up a few steps from where you have guided as shown above, but it gets even more complicated. May I know how should I approach it?

Comment: Hi, can you help me with it?